# Why does my offset not increase when I call my increment offset method in Silverstripe?

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm calling my `IncrementOffset()` method from my template file in my Silverstripe project. The expected result is that each time the method is called, the private offset property will increment by 1. The offset methods look like this:

```
class NewPage extends Page {
    public function IncrementOffset() { $this->offset++; }
    public function ResetOffset() { $this->offset = 0; }
    public function Offset() { return $this->offset; }
}
```

In my NewPage.ss template, I have the following code:

```
<% loop $InfoPanels %>
    <% if not $Description %>
        <div class="span3">
            <h4 align="center">$Title</h4>
            <a href="{$ButtonURL}" target="blank"><div style="background: url('{$Image.SetSize(225, 225).URL}') no-repeat center center; width: 225px; height: 225px;" class="center3"></div></a>
            <a href="{$ButtonURL}" target="blank" class="btn btn-block">$ButtonLabel</a>
            </div>
        <% if $MultipleOf(3, $Top.Offset()) %>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
        <% end_if %>
    <% else %>
        $Top.IncrementOffset()
    <% end_if %>
<% end_loop %>
<p>Offset is: $Offset</p>
```

The resulting output of the Offset print after calling `IncrementOffset()` is:

> Offset is: 0

Can anyone please tell me if I'm missing something obvious here? I just can't understand why this isn't working. It seems like it should be such a simple thing to me.

Comment: I've never used silverstripe, but shouldn't you get the value from `$Top.Offset()` instead of `$Offset`?

Comment: $Top is not a variable as the others, its a scope thing and always refers to the outer most scope. So this is actually correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because template variables are cached on first access.

Your problem is explained in the SilverStripe documentation on templates, section 'Side effects'

Here are some variables you might find useful:

- `$Pos` the current pos inside the loop. will be 1,2,3,4,5,...
- `$Pos(2)` pos with starting point, if I am not mistaken it will be 2,3,4,5,6,...
- `$MultipleOf(3)` should work without passing a a 2nd argument
- `$InfoPanels.Count` number of items

---

EDIT after conversation in comments:

if you want to filter out some items, you should do that before looping them:

in php:

```
public function FilteredInfoPanels() {
    $dataList = $this->InfoPanels();
    // only get items of which the Description is not ''
    $dataList = $dataList->filter('Description:not', ''); 
    return $dataList;
}
```

in the themplate:

```
<% loop $InfoPanels %>
        <div class="span3">
            <h4 align="center">$Title</h4>
            <a href="{$ButtonURL}" target="blank"><div style="background: url('{$Image.SetSize(225, 225).URL}') no-repeat center center; width: 225px; height: 225px;" class="center3"></div></a>
            <a href="{$ButtonURL}" target="blank" class="btn btn-block">$ButtonLabel</a>
            </div>
        <% if $MultipleOf(3) %>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
        <% end_if %>
<% end_loop %>
<p>Number of filtered Panels is: $FilteredInfoPanels.Count</p>
<p>Number of Panels is: $InfoPanels.Count</p>
```

Comment: I had a feeling that it was caching the variable. Is there any way to have Silverstripe fetch a fresh variable each time? I need some way of capturing the offset each time the template hits the `<% else %>` block.

Comment: not that I am aware of. but I am sure there is another way to do what you are trying to do. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with the offset?

Comment: I only want to display items that have a `$Description`, which is what the main If block is for. Every 4 items, I want to break out of the current row and start a new one (see the nested If). I can't use $MultipleOf() as this doesn't use the actual number of Items that have already been output. 

I guess I should manipulate the list before it goes to the template?